# Capture the value of counter - functional scope

Tags: javascript, scope

The code passed the `if` condition, but couldn't capture the change of `counter`. The value of `counter` is still 0 after the whole process.

```
 let counter = 0;
            database
            .collection("bookings")
            .get()
            .then((snapshot) => {
                snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
                    var booking = doc.data();
                    if (((booking.paxGroup === paxGroup) && (booking.restaurantName === restName)) 
                    && ((booking.mallName === mallName) && (booking.queueStatus === "waiting"))) {
                        counter += 1;
                    }
                })
            });
            alert(counter)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You have a race condition here

Here's what's happening

```
let counter = 0;        // Synchronous

database....then(...)   // Asynchronous (needs to wait on fetching data)

alert(counter);         // Synchronous
```

And so the order in which the code runs is

```
let counter = 0;        // 1

alert(counter);         // 2

database....then(...)   // 3 (after the database's get() call is complete)
```

#### How to double check this:

Go ahead and place another `alert(counter)` under `counter += 1` and you'll see that the counter is incremented.

Comment: So, to return the counter with with the correct value, should I do: `return database...then...then({return counter; })`?

Comment: Yes. But keep in mind that `return database...then...then...return counter` will immediately return a Promise to the callee. That means that you need to use `await` or use `.then` whenever you want to use the actual counter value. Here are some some resources to help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then, and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Answer (score 0):

Your counter is still 0, is because the alert(counter) runs before the execution of counter +=1;

The reason is that the database.collection("bookings").get() is a Promise. That means that the function inside the brackets, runs as an asynchronous function and thats why this code runs in its own time.

You can read more about Promises [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).